# Simplification of a calculation with trigonometric functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

A few years back, I had calculated values for a complex SVG graphic. I don't remember exactly how the formulas came about, but I would like to simplify them (if possible). Unfortunately, my knowledge of math is limited. Can the following two terms be simplified?

$$\cos (α) · \Bigl( \cos (-α) · x - \sin (-α) · y + \bigl(1 - \cos (-α)\bigr) · (x + r) + \sin (-α) · (y + r) \Bigr)$$
$$- \sin (α) · \Bigl( \sin (-α) · x + \cos (-α) · y + \bigl(1 - \cos (-α)\bigr) · (y + r ) - \sin (-α) · (x + r) \Bigr)$$
$$+ \bigl(1 - \cos (α)\bigr) · 1250 + \sin (α) · 1250$$

---

$$\sin (α) · \Bigl( \cos (-α) · x - \sin (-α) · y + \bigl(1 - \cos (-α)\bigr) · (x + r) + \sin (-α) · (y + r) \Bigr)$$
$$+ \cos (α) · \Bigl( \sin (-α) · x + \cos (-α) · y + \bigl(1 - \cos (-α)\bigr) · (y + r ) - \sin (-α) · (x + r) \Bigr)$$
$$+ \bigl(1 - \cos (α)\bigr) · 1250 - \sin (α) · 1250$$

Comment: For a start, note that $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$ and $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the abbreviations

$$ s := \sin(\alpha), \qquad c := \cos(\alpha), \qquad K := 1250. $$

The two expressions simplify to

$$ (K-r)\cdot(1-c+s) + c\cdot x - s\cdot y $$

and

$$ (K-r)\cdot(1-c-s) + c\cdot y + s\cdot x. $$